# How to handle multiple paths between two nodes in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I would like to handle multiple paths between 2 nodes in neo4j.E.g

I have two connected nodes (flights and destination) in an ER Graph. I have another graph with the following words in the nodes:

1.flights leaving from destination

2.flights from destination

3.flights leaving destination

4.flights available from destination

I join the ER graph with this other graph using something like:

```
match(a:iknode)-[r]-(b:iknode)-[r2]-(c:iknode) 
match(d:flights17)-[r1]-(e:flights17) 
where  d.alias contains a.name and b.name = type(r1) 
set e.f =c.name
```

How do I capture all the scenarios? I would prefer variable path lengths. Could this be solved by using regex in neo4j?

Thanks

Comment: the solution will depend of the result you want. Can you specify it ? And is it a OR or a AND on conditions 1 & 2 ?

Comment: Seems the :iknodes are representative of words or concepts. I would assume order matters? If so, you really need to have directions to your relationships, or you might end up with matches with the same nodes in reversed order.

Also you said you had pairs of flights and destinations in your graph, but your example query has two connected flights instead. Is that a typo?

Comment: In the flights graph, d is flight whereas e is destination. r is from, leaving etc.

Comment: You may want to revise your example then, if there's a distinction between nodes used as a flight verses a destination. Seems like these would use different labels, and contain different properties and have different relationships.

Comment: I do not intend to change the labels for now. I will consider this in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

I think I will go with ANY function for the time being. If any of the words are present in the relation, it is valid. Should work. If you have a better solution, please let me know.